# Weird Behaviour in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I was working with Django Forms , I was doing custom validation for a field, but encountered weird problem.

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=50)        

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        print(self.cleaned_data) # all fields are present except password1 in cleaned Data
        re_password = self.cleaned_data['password1'] #Gives Key Error here
        # Do something
```

Here when I try to do some validation for password field in `clean_password` function, It gives key error for `password1` field ,I don't get why that happens. I tried searching a lot but couldn't find anything relevant, about what causes this error.But then I tried making some change in code and It worked but I don't know why it worked.

**modified_forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=50)    #swapped position    
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        print(self.cleaned_data) # all fields are present in cleaned Data
        re_password = self.cleaned_data['password1'] #Doesn't Give Key Error here
        # Do something
```

The changes I made was I just **swapped** the line position of `password1` and `password` ,that is I just changed the order of `password` and `password1`. I changed order `password1` at line of `password`, `password` at position where was `password1`. And it solved error I don't understand this behaviour from what I know field order shouldn't effect anything. Can someone please explain what is happening here? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not weird behavior. Django forms work this way. Please look at the source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9358da704ea9ba55f22df912e47b54eb85d5c97e/django/forms/forms.py#L378) to understand how field cleaning works for django forms. Here is a stripped down version of `_clean_fields` method.

```
def _clean_fields(self):
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        # skipped
        try:
            # skipped
            value = field.clean(value)
            self.cleaned_data[name] = value
            if hasattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name):
                # skipped
                value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
                self.cleaned_data[name] = value
        except ValidationError as e:
            self.add_error(name, e)
```

What it does is loop over form fields, and for every field, puts its cleaned value in `cleaned_data` dict. If a method for cleaning field (`clean_<FIELD_NAME>`) is defined, it calls that method on cleaned data for that field and puts it in `cleaned_data` dict.

In your first case `password1` comes after `password`. Because fields are cleaned in order, `password1` is not yet cleaned when you are trying to access it in `clean_password` method. Which means its cleaned value is not yet present in `cleaned_data` dict.

In second case, you swap the position of `password` and `password1`. Now cleaning has been performed for `password1` and you can access its value.

The rule of thumb is that **for `clean_<FIELD_NAME>` method, you can only access cleaned values of those fields that are declared before that specific field**.

#### Solution

You should do this as django does in its [UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L81). They check password match on second field i-e password1 should match password not vice versa (which is essentially same). Snippet with modification from [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L112) .

```
def clean_password1(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
    if password and password1 and password != password1:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match')
    return password1
```

Answer (score 1):

You use python. python is scripting type language and use interpreter so code will evaluate line by line

> in your case you create `def clean_password(self)` so this method call after taking password from form in lazy evaluation. if you rename your method without swapping of `password` and `password1`  rename you method with `def clean_password1(self)` it work fine

**forms.py**

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=50)        

    def clean_password1(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        print(self.cleaned_data) # all fields are present
        re_password = self.cleaned_data['password1']
```

if you satisfied of my answer let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better practise to make separate clean methods for `password` and `password1` fields

```
def clean_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    # Do something

def clean_password1(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
    # Do something
```

Or validate both in [clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) method

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    password = cleaned_data['password']
    re_password = cleaned_data['password1']
    # Do something
```